# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(JSON?, Error?) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am having an error of

```
        EduappRestClient.request(with: URLString, method: .post, parameters: parameters) { (json, error) in
        guard error == nil, let json = json else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(QuestionModel.self, from: json)
        completion(result, nil)
    }
```

it's an API i am calling and my full source code can be found at 
https://github.com/WilliamLoke/quizApp

may i know what is the issue i am getting this line of error code?

Comment: It looks like the function expects a block that doesn't throw, but you're using `try` outside of a `do {} catch` block. Try wrapping the throwing portion of your function in a `do catch`, or use `try?`.

Comment: @WilliamLoke Please read the [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) chapter in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this block is not expected to throw an error, you need to wrap your throwing call in a `do catch` block:

```
EduappRestClient.request(with: URLString, method: .post, parameters: parameters) { (json, error) in
    guard error == nil, let json = json else {
        completion(nil, error)
        return
    }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(QuestionModel.self, from: json)
        completion(result, nil)
    } catch let error {
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and the solution is easy: you can just use *try?* instead of *try*

```
guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(QuestionModel.self, from: json)
```

Comment: The solution is too *easy*, you are discouraged from ignoring `DecodingError`s

Comment: This will return a nil value instead of propagating the error thrown.